# auto fit image in div / jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, image-size

How can I auto-fit an image if my code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    function animate() {
        jQuery(".fadein").eq(count).fadeIn(1000);
        count++;
        if(count <= jQuery(".fadein").length) {
            setTimeout(animate, 1000);
        } else {
            jQuery("a.fadein").fadeOut(1000);
            count = 0;
            animate();
        }      
    }
    animate();
});
</script>
```

Would this be correct?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0;
        function animate() {
            jQuery(".fadein").eq(count).fadeIn(1000);
            count++;
            if(count <= jQuery(".fadein").length) {
                setTimeout(animate, 1000);
            } else {
                jQuery("a.fadein").fadeOut(1000);
                count = 0;
                animate();
            }      
        }
        animate();
    })
            function fitImagetoContainer() {   $("img").each(function(i) {
     $(this).width($(this).parent().width()); //or your logic   
       }); }

//Call the function at load 
      $(window).load(function() {    fitImagetoContainer(); });


//Also call the function when the window resizes  
      $(window).resize(function() {    fitImagetoContainer(); });;
    </script>
```

Comment: I think you're missing some markup there.

Comment: What do you mean by autofit? What would you like to happen if the image is smaller than the container, larger than the container?

Comment: @arasmussen: What I meant is, if I resize the browser then the image will also follow the size of the image. Is that possible?

Comment: @Marcel: I took a part of this in HTML

Comment: Are you able to link to a demo of what you have? JavaScript is only part of the puzzle really. For instance, some basic CSS may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my throw at your problem

```
//Create a function to resize the image with respect to parent
function fitImagetoContainer() {
  $("img").each(function(i) {
     $(this).width($(this).parent().width()); //or your logic
  });
}

//Call the function at load
$(window).load(function() {
   fitImagetoContainer();
});


//Also call the function when the window resizes 
$(window).resize(function() {
   fitImagetoContainer();
});
```

Comment: @tintincutes, Yeah, but outside the `$(document).ready();` part

Comment: @tintincutes, Yeah, but fix the comment, it is commenting the code part too.

Comment: I tried but it didn't change the size of the image. If I resize the browser the image is out of range.

Comment: I read in your code you have this included: $"img" - Do I have to put the link of the image here?

Comment: No, It selects all the images on the page. Can you create a demo of your page on jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how to add it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9732/discussion-between-tintincutes-and-starx)

Comment: @tintincutes, You are not using any image tags, you are using backgrounds. Background resizing is not supported by most of the browser.

Comment: Thank you will try this and will let you know for the feedback. Happy Easter

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the css. Its better and more maintainable.

Just add this to your image css.

```
.fadein img {width: 100%; height: auto;} //This maintains the aspect ratio.
```

If you want the image to fill the container no matter what:

```
.fadein img {width: 100%; height: 100%;} //This distorts the image to fill the container
```